# Filter my DataGridView

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` `enter code here`in a windows form that I generated from datasource by dragging and dropping the object into the form.

The rows display correctly from the datasource and i want to be able to filter them by specific column them using a `TextBox`.

My binding source is called "customerBindingSource".

I tried this :

```
private void _txtFilterEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  customerBindingSource.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
  customerBindingSource.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + 
                                 "LIKE '%" +   _txtFilterEmail.Text + "%'";
 dataGridView1.DataSource = customerBindingSource.DataSource;
 }
```

But when I type something in the `TextBox`, nothing happens.

I'm fairly new to windows forms and EntityFramework.

Comment: does the headertext differ form datapropertyname in datasource?

Comment: No, I tested before, they are the same.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + "LIKE '%"` there is a space missing before `LIKE`

Comment: I Added the space between " and LIKE  but still no filtering.

Comment: Is there a space in the HeaderText? or is the HeaderText a text which is a keyword?

Comment: HeaderText is  Email. I want to filter customers by email.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type..

Answer (score 1):

This assigns the **unfiltered** `DataSource` as the DGV's `DataSource`:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = customerBindingSource.DataSource;
```

Instead the `BindingSource` itself should be assigned:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = customerBindingSource;
```

Btw:  I don't think that it is a good idea to rely on the `HeaderText` to contain the name of the `Column`. Instead you should use a more reliable property. This comes to mind, untested:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[yourColumnIndex].DataPropertyName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private void _txtFilterEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
        string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'",
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString(),
        _txtFilterEmail.Text);
}
```

or use this:

```
private void _txtFilterEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
     bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
     bs.Filter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'",
     dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString(), _txtFilterEmail.Text);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it raised a NullReferenceException in this part : `dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString()`

Comment: add hooks to the column name [{0}] like the answer, and check if you put a correct index of column [1]. Or try to use the 2nd proposition.

Comment: I add the hooks as you asked, it still yield the same exception. The second proposition does not work for me, the datagridview is not filtered.

Comment: put this statement in your code and tell me the type displayed to know the type of your datasource; `MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.DataSource.GetType().ToString());`